# how write socket server in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, sockets

i wrote a code in php that make a socket server and it worked:

```
<?php

$host = "127.0.0.1";
$port = 25003;
set_time_limit(0);
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");
$result = socket_listen($socket, 3) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");

$spawn = socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");
$input = socket_read($spawn, 1024) or die("Could not read input\n");
$input = trim($input);
echo "Client Message : ".$input;
$output = strrev($input) . "\n";
socket_write($spawn, $output, strlen ($output)) or die("Could not write output\n");
socket_close($spawn);
socket_close($socket);
?>
```

then i moved that code in a laravel controller. like this:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{     
    function socket_server()
    {
        // code above
    }
}
```

but i get this error:

```
socket_create() has been disabled for security reasons
```

how i can write socket server in laravel?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write socket server from scratch, believe me it is already done just fine. Look at [laravel broadcasting docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/broadcasting) , you can use [laravel-websockets](https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/) or [laravel-echo-server](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server) to broadcast your data via sockets

Answer (score 0):

> `socket_create() has been disabled for security reasons`

If you receive that it's not possible to create such server in any way with PHP. Contact your server provider and ask them to enable the command. If you're working locally make sure the function is not disabled in php.ini

---

I start by saying *it is* painful to write a socket server from scratch, especially because PHP was not design for duplex connections in the first place.

To answer your question it depends on project; you can use third party services such as Pusher.com which are already supported by Laravel. If you don't want to use third party services and have more freedom I recommend Ratchet for socket servers: http://socketo.me Project is highly continued and easy to use/implement.